# Convert from 24 hour time to Datetime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, date, time

Hi i have a string 2300H i want to convert this to standard date time (Datetime) Object in C#
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2300H", @"HHmm\H", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

if you need the time

```
var time = dt.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are only dealing with the time portion it might be better to put it into a TimeSpan structure using a ParseExact like here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370.aspx

The code that L.B supplied will give it to you in a DateTime but you're gonna get values that aren't accurate for the day, month year stuff. If it suits your design you could use the same code to store your information in a TimeSpan instead:

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("2300H", @"hhmm\H", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Unless you happen to know the day as well as the time I think this is a better way of doing it but its hard to say without knowing more about your system or what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Really? k I will fix it one sec

Comment: I think you are missing a namespace for System.Globalization it builds just fine on my machine

Comment: For timespan you need lowercase "h" for hour: `@"hhmm\H"` (DateTime does need upper case HH for 24 hour time.)

Comment: Yah thanks guys I just realized that too had to go back to the TimeSpan formats. I forgot that it used lower case h for hours

Answer (score 1):

The following will return a `DateTime` whose date is the current date, Kind is Unspecified, and time is equal to the supplied time (23:00):

```
string s = "2300H";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, @"HHmm\H", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or the following will return a `DateTime` whose date is 01 January 0001, Kind is Unspecified, and time is equal to the supplied time (23:00):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s, @"HHmm\H", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

Comment: No it won't return `01 January 0001`. It will return `today`

Comment: @L.B - try it!  If you specify DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, it will return 01 January 0001.